# Python venv module not creating clean environment

Tags: python, python-venv

I created a virtual environment using venv module of python.

```
python -m venv myenv
```

After activating environment using `source  myenv/bin/activate`, I am getting systemwide packages already there in the `myenv`. I am getting strange result as:

```
(myenv) $ pip list
Package       Version
------------- -------
pip           20.0.2 
pkg-resources 0.0.0  
setuptools    44.0.0
```

and when I do

```
(myenv) $ python -m pip list
#...Getting long list of packages present in the systemwide python packages
```

I failed to understand this strange result

System details:
OS: Ubuntu 20.04
Python: 3.8.10

*Edit:* Here is the location of pip and python packages

```
(myenv) $ which pip
/home/user/myenv/bin/pip
(myenv) $ which python
/home/user/myenv/bin/python
```

Comment: can you check version/path pip and python by `pip --version`

Comment: @Nguyen `pip 20.0.2 from /home/user/myenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip (python 3.8)`

Comment: try with `/home/user/myenv/bin/python3.8 - m pip list`

Comment: @Nguyen, There is no python3.8 binary, but there is python3. So `/home/user/myenv/bin/python3 -m pip list` gives clean/minimal packages. But wonder what is the problem with `/home/user/myenv/bin/python` binary? Why does it carry systemwide packages?

Comment: i do some research and take a look at venv lib [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.4/Lib/venv/__init__.py)

Comment: Virtual env access to the system site-packages dir is a option. 
Probably is `python -m pip list` is not same path with `/home/user/myenv/bin/python`